# How to make the game engine render stereo on 2 monitors?

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to use the game engine to display side-by-side stereo on two monitors. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have been successful using the standalone player to display side-by-side stereo on a single monitor, but I need each image to go to the corresponding monitor.

Also, when I disable 'fullscreen', I have been able to make a large window (2x 1600) display across both monitors. The problem is that the player starts on the right-most monitor, forcing me to drag the window onto the left-most monitor. The window border is not desirable either.

Answer (score 6):

You need to setup your desktop to "span" across both screens.

This way both screen areas will be treated as a single desktop. How to accomplish that depends on your OS and graphic card. A good way to test if it's working is to take any application (not-Blender) and see if maximizing it takes over both screens or only one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it appears since Windows Vista NVIDIA display no longer offer a 'span' display option, in the old sense. 'Extend' is similar, allowing applications to make windows that cover multiple displays. However, Blender was not defining its game engine window to cover this distance. I modified the source and discovered the changes needed to support span of the GE window across multiple displays. I will work with the developers to contribute this feature addition.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a patch being worked on](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?296223-help-testing-desktop-span-feature-addition) for BGE (on Windows) that allows you to span BGE (both in blender and in player). It is not yet accepted into Blender yet, but I'm quite confident it'll be added at some point. At the time of writing Blender 2.68 release is being prepared, so no further patches are accepted, but I imagine that after this release I could work with @dfelinto on reviewing and committing the patch (I've worked already with the developer of the patch to test).

From the linked thread you'll find builds to test with.